# Checking if two SQL queries return equivalent data

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I need to check if two queries are returning equivalent data from a particular instance (I realize that this does not imply that they will be equivalent over all instances). However, I do not care about the ordering of said data.

I am currently using:

```
(userQuery EXCEPT answerQuery) UNION ALL (answerQuery EXCEPT userQuery)
```

However, this tells me:

```
"SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employee" != "SELECT last_name, first_name FROM employee"
"SELECT id, first_name FROM employee ORDER BY id" != "SELECT id, first_name FROM employee"
```

Basically, it should return correct regardless of the ordering of the columns or attributes

Comment: You tagged this with `mysql` **and** `postgresql`. Which DBMS are you really using?

Comment: I am implementing it across both, and I am pretty certain I can apply any help with this problem to each.

Comment: I don't think MySQL has EXCEPT as an operation.  What are you executing on your MySQL instance?

Comment: Something along the lines of "userQuery WHERE NOT IN(answerQuery)".

Comment: Union all combined with the two except clauses seems right. What is the question, if that isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: If you look, I mentioned "However, this tells me:". That is my problem. I'm thinking of just adding both results to a multiset and finding what isn't there twice.

Comment: "*Basically, it should return correct regardless of the ordering of the columns or attributes*" - no it shouldn't. The ordering of the columns **does** matter for `except` (as it does for `intersect` and `union`). `select 1,2 except select 2,1` is something different than `select 1,2 except select 1,2`. This is similar to the fact that `select 1,2 union select 1,2` will return something different than `select 1,2 union select 2,1`

Comment: You misunderstood me. I wasn't saying that the query I listed should be returning that, but that the query I am looking for should.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this help?

SELECT * 
FROM   [query1] 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [query2] WHERE [query1 key] = [query2 key])

and then union that with the same query the other way around.  If it returns nothing, then both queries are equivalent.